# can new Macbook of apple supports simultaneous charging & data transfer through usb type C port?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging

does macbook has capability to handle both charging of laptop & data transfer simultaneously. i have the hub which has three type c connectors 1.) dedicated charger port connected to charger 2.)downstream port of that hub is used for data transfer 3) Type C port which can be connected to Macbook.

i will take care of all CC signals & D+,D- and other signals. I want to know whether apple permits both simultaneous charging & data transfer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you intend to do, but at the most basic level the answer to your question is yes.

The Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports on the 2016 and 2017 MacBook Pros can simultaneously support charging and data transfer. **However, this will be dependent on the cables/adapters/hubs/docks etc being used.** If they support/allow both charging and data transfer then you should have no problems.

In summary, the Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports support each of the following:

- Charging
- DisplayPort
- Thunderbolt (up to 40 Gbps)
- USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gbps)

**[UPDATE]**

If you're after independent verification that multiple features are supported *simultaneously*, then refer to [Using USB-C and Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports and adapters on your Mac notebook](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204360). You'll notice, for example, that under the heading *USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter* it states:

> The USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter allows you to **simultaneously**:
>
> - Charge your Mac.
> - Connect to other standard USB (USB-A) devices or hubs.
> - Connect your Mac to external HDMI video devices such as a TV, projector, or display.

<sup>**NOTE:** Bold emphasis mine.</sup>

Now, as I mentioned previously, a lot gets down to what is supported by the individual cable, adapter, etc. For example, even about its USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter, Apple says that:

- The USB-A port on the adapter supports data transfer at up to 5 Gbps (USB 3.1 Gen 1) and can be used to connect standard USB devices or hubs.
- The USB-C port on the adapter charges your computer, but it doesn't transfer data.

Note how the USB-A port on this adapter only supports speeds of up to 5 Gbps, while the MBP supports USB speeds up to 10 Gbps. Also note how USB-C port on this particular adapter is limited to only charging. However, the USB-C port on the MBP is not limited in this way, because the [USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=4c) connects to it and then provides simultaneous functionality to all three of its ports for charging, USB-A devices and HDMI devices.

Now, depending on your specific model of MacBook Pro (you don't specify), the data transfer speeds may vary depending on the port used. More specifically:

> **Thunderbolt 3 data speeds per MacBook Pro port**
>
> MacBook Pro models introduced in 2016 vary slightly in the data speeds
>   they provide to each Thunderbolt 3 port:
>
> - MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016) delivers full Thunderbolt 3 performance on all four ports.
> - MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) supports Thunderbolt 3 at full performance using the two left-hand ports. The
>     two right-hand ports deliver Thunderbolt 3 functionality, but have
>     reduced PCI Express bandwidth.
>     *Always plug higher-performance devices into the left-hand ports on MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) for maximum data
>     throughput.*
> - MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 Ports) delivers full Thunderbolt 3 performance on both ports.
>
> **About USB speed**
>
> For USB devices, all 2016 MacBook Pro models deliver USB 3.1 Gen 2 (10
>   Gbps) performance on all Thunderbolt 3 ports.
>
> Use a USB-C to USB adapter to connect a USB-A device or cable to a
>   Thunderbolt 3 port on your MacBook Pro. Use a USB 3.1 (USB-C to USB-C)
>   cable to connect a USB-C device.

<sup>**Source:** [Connect with Thunderbolt 3 on your new MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT207256)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the instant response. when done charging & data transfer seprately its working absolutely fine in my customise Hub. But simultaneous is not occuring charging of Macbook is always taken on priority i.e when data transfer is taking place and i plugged in charger in my hub then data transfers stops and charging starts.so basically am not able to do both at same time. But can you give me any article,link or document that mentions about above task ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional information.